# Why does calculating pi using a loop not work correctly?

Tags: java

We got an assignment where we have to calculate the value of pi using the formula `pi/4=1-1/3+1/5-1/7+1/9-1/11...`(using `100` terms) but it doesn't seem to run the while-loop for some reason. We're students who have no prior experience of writing code and are just starting.

```
double pi = 1;
int count = 0;
int n = 3;

while (count < 100) {
    if ((count&1) == 0) {  
        pi = pi - 1 / n;
    } else {
        pi = pi + 1 / n;
    }
    n = n + 2;
    count++;
}
out.print(pi*4);   //why is it printing out pi=1?????
```

Comment: first your 'if ' is wrong. && use this.

Comment: 1/n will be always 0 as you are divide int by int and result is int also

Comment: consider using += or -= operators to increment/decrement your variable

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is **you do not type cast**. `pi` is double but `1/n` returns int, since both the denominator and numerator are integers. This happens in JAVA. Basically, every time, `1/n` which is actually fractional, returns `0` (int) for every `n > 1` due to lack of type casting. So `pi`'s value is always 1 and in the end `pi*4` displays 4.0. So you have to convert (cast) the numerator or the denominator as fractional (double) to make 1/n fractional.

To solve the problem, change the statements

```
pi = pi + 1 / n;
pi = pi - 1 / n;
```

to

```
pi = pi + 1.0 / (double) n;
pi = pi - 1.0 / (double) n;
```

This displays the output as **3.1514934010709914**.

Comment: no need to cast n as double since 1.0 is a double, the result will be a double

Comment: @NicolasFilotto yes. But that's just to show the OP what exactly I'm trying to do. Plus it helps understand better.

Comment: thank you. we solved it by declaring n as a double though. at the time we were still learning about int and double.